# ActiveRecordの属性 (attribute) を日本語化する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

フォームのメニューが日本語化できなくて困っています。
やったこととしては以下の手順です。

1.config/application.rb

`config.i18n.default_locale = :ja` を記述

2.config/locales/ja.ymlには

```yaml
ja:
   users:
      contact_email: "通知メールアドレス"
      jp_market_place_id: "amazon.jpマーケットプレイスID"
      jp_markchant_id: "amazon.jpマーチャントプレイスID"
      jp_access_key_id: "amazon.jpアクセスキーID"
      jp_secret_key: "amazon.jpシークレットキー"
      com_market_place_id: "comマーケットプレイスID"
      com_markchant_id: "comマーチャントプレイスID"
      com_access_key_id: "comアクセスキーID"
      com_secret_key: "comシークレットキー"
```

を記述してます。

3.views/users/edit.htmlには

```html
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :contact_email %>
      <%= f.text_field :contact_email %>
･
･
･
```

といろいろ続きます。

上記設定したのですがメニューを見るとメニューがContact emailのままで変更されません。。

Answer (score 2):

以下のような構造で記述すると、日本語化できます。

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      users:
        contact_email: "通知メールアドレス"
        ...
```

詳細は、[Active Recordモデルで翻訳を行なう](http://railsguides.jp/i18n.html#active-record%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%86) (公式ドキュメントの翻訳) を参照してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。言われた通りやってみたのですがダメでした。